# Getting byte[] from PropertyInfo returns NULL

Tags: c#, reflection, arrays, propertyinfo

I'm trying to get a Byte[] using reflection. Unfortunately the result it always NULL. The property is filled with data. Here's my code snippet.

```
public static void SaveFile(BusinessObject document)
{
    Type boType = document.GetType();
    PropertyInfo[] propertyInfo = boType.GetProperties();
    Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(boType);
    foreach (PropertyInfo item in propertyInfo)
    {
        Type xy = item.PropertyType;
        if (String.Equals(item.Name, "Content") && (item.PropertyType == typeof(Byte[])))
        {
            Byte[] content = item.GetValue(obj, null) as Byte[];
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here's the working code:

```
    public static void SaveFile(BusinessObject document)
{
    Type boType = document.GetType();
    PropertyInfo[] propertyInfo = boType.GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo item in propertyInfo)
    {
        if (String.Equals(item.Name, "Content") && (item.PropertyType == typeof(Byte[])))
        {
            Byte[] content = item.GetValue(document, null) as Byte[];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code looks strange. You are creating a *new* instance of the type of the parameter and try to get the value from that instance. You should be using the parameter itself instead:

```
public static void SaveFile(BusinessObject document)
{
    Type boType = document.GetType();
    PropertyInfo[] propertyInfo = boType.GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo item in propertyInfo)
    {
        Type xy = item.PropertyType;
        if (String.Equals(item.Name, "Content") &&
            (item.PropertyType == typeof(Byte[])))
        {
            Byte[] content = item.GetValue(document, null) as Byte[];
        }
    }
}
```

---

BTW:

1. `return true` in a method that returns `void` is illegal and will lead to a compiler error.
2. There is no need to use reflection in your case. You could simply write this:

   ```
   public static void SaveFile(BusinessObject document)
   {
       Byte[] content = document.Content;
       // do something with content.
   }
   ```

   This is only true if `Content` is defined on `BusinessObject` and not only on derived classes.

Comment: Re BTW 2: Maybe Content is only a property of a derived class.

Comment: Hi Daniel. Of course you're absolutely right. How could I be so blind. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

from your code snippet it appears you are not populating any value.

```
Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(boType);
```

this would just invoke the default consturctor and assign default values for all types.
and for byte[] it is *null*

it should be

```
item.GetValue(document, null)
```